# How to Add custom places using Google places API in android

Tags: android, google-places-api

Hi I am developing an application in which i wish to open maps with my current location. And after showing the current location i wish to open some of the custom places to show some description or information regarding. One way i found is using markers. Is that the only way to achieve this. I have gone through google places api and found a way [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/add-place). But when i try to implement it. I am getting an error in my  code

```
com.example.vivek.yes, PID: 2644
10-20 14:11:56.729 2644-2644/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vivek.yes/com.example.vivek.yes.HomePlacesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: GoogleApiClient must not be null
```

the code which i have written for adding the places in the api are

```
AddPlaceRequest place =
                new AddPlaceRequest(
                        "Manly Sea Life Sanctuary", // Name
                        new LatLng(-33.7991, 151.2813), // Latitude and longitude
                        "W Esplanade, Manly NSW 2095", // Address
                        Collections.singletonList(Place.TYPE_AQUARIUM), // Place types
                        "+61 1800 199 742", // Phone number
                        Uri.parse("http://www.manlysealifesanctuary.com.au/") // Website
                );

        Places.GeoDataApi.addPlace(mGoogleApiClient, place)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                        /*Log.i(TAG, "Place add result: " + places.getStatus().toString());
                        Log.i(TAG, "Added place: " + places.get(0).getName().toString());*/
                        places.release();
                    }
                });
```

which is also taken from the native google developers reference. Please suggest me a way how to achieve this. Should i stop implementing this approach move ahead with markers.??
edit 1: Adding the complete code

```
package com.example.vivek.yes;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class HomePlacesActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    Spinner mSprPlaceType;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    String[] mPlaceType = null;
    String[] mPlaceTypeName = null;

    double mLatitude = 0;
    double mLongitude = 0;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homeplaces);

        // Array of place types
        mPlaceType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type);

        // Array of place type names
        mPlaceTypeName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type_name);

        // Creating an array adapter with an array of Place types
        // to populate the spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mPlaceTypeName);
        Button btnFind;
        // Getting reference to Find Button
        btnFind = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);

        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        } else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
            SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting Google Map
            mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location From GPS
            try {
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                if (location != null) {
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                }

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
            }
            catch (SecurityException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Setting click event lister for the find button
            btnFind.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int selectedPosition = mSprPlaceType.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    String type = mPlaceType[selectedPosition];

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                    sb.append("location="+mLatitude+","+mLongitude);
                    sb.append("&radius=5000");
                    sb.append("&sensor=true");
                    sb.append("&key=AIzaSyA0z5zRlZCsJv3jU5OvTmt51Op7h_zZVVs");

                    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download json data
                    PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();

                    // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
                    placesTask.execute(sb.toString());

                }
            });

        }
        /*mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();


        AddPlaceRequest place =
                new AddPlaceRequest(
                        "Manly Sea Life Sanctuary", // Name
                        new LatLng(-33.7991, 151.2813), // Latitude and longitude
                        "W Esplanade, Manly NSW 2095", // Address
                        Collections.singletonList(Place.TYPE_AQUARIUM), // Place types
                        "+61 1800 199 742", // Phone number
                        Uri.parse("http://www.manlysealifesanctuary.com.au/") // Website
                );

        Places.GeoDataApi.addPlace(mGoogleApiClient, place)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                        *//*Log.i(TAG, "Place add result: " + places.getStatus().toString());
                        Log.i(TAG, "Added place: " + places.get(0).getName().toString());*//*
                        places.release();
                    }
                });
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();*/


    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    /** A class, to download Google Places */
    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        String data = null;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try{
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
            // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }

    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

        JSONObject jObject;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
            PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list){

            // Clears all the existing markers
            mGoogleMap.clear();

            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

                // Creating a marker
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Getting a place from the places list
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);

                // Getting latitude of the place
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));

                // Getting longitude of the place
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

                // Getting name
                String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

                // Getting vicinity
                String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                // Setting the position for the marker
                markerOptions.position(latLng);

                // Setting the title for the marker.
                //This will be displayed on taping the marker
                markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);

                // Placing a marker on the touched position
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_places, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is instructive.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: GoogleApiClient must not be null

You have not initialised your GoogleApiClient.

Taken from the [Google Places API for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start)

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
        .Builder(this)
        .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
        .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Also make sure you have your keys and the correct tags in your manifest.

Comment: Hi, I tried following your suggestion but getting an error like

Comment: Sorry. I missed pasting my error. and I also will be editing my question and adding the complete code.

This is the error:

10-20 22:37:14.750 21137-21137/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.vivek.yes, PID: 21137
10-20 22:37:14.750 21137-21137/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vivek.yes/com.example.vivek.yes.HomePlacesActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.